# Spring MVC ServletContext and ApplicationContext

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller

I am currently learning Spring MVC. I came across a piece code which is bit confusing to me.
In Spring MVC, there is this concept of `DispatcherServlet`.

Each `DispatcherServlet` is registered in the `ServletContext` and each `DispatcherServlet` has its own `applicationContext`. But now the code that is confusing to me is below one.

```
public class AppInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {
 
    public void onStartup(ServletContext container) throws ServletException {
 
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        ctx.register(AppConfig.class);
        ctx.setServletContext(container);
 
        ServletRegistration.Dynamic servlet = container.addServlet(
                "dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(ctx));
 
        servlet.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        servlet.addMapping("/");
    }
 
}
```

If you see the above code in the `onStartUp` method,

1. I am creating a instance of a `ApplicationContext`.
2. I am registering the beans in the application context.
3. And then this is the line I have the doubt ..what does the line of code do?
   `ctx.setServletContext(container);`

Does it provide a `servletContext` to the `applicationContext`?
What does the method `setServletContext()` mean here? I read the documentation, but it is not clear. It simply says Set the `ServletContext` for this web application context.

But why do we need to set the `ServletContext` to the application context? Is this line of code mandatory? Kindly help in clarifying it.
Is application context registered in the `ServletContext`?

I went through the code of `createServletApplicationContext()` method in the `AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer` class. There in the method the `servletContext` is never set in the application Context. Please refer the method below.

```
@Override
    protected WebApplicationContext createServletApplicationContext() {
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        Class<?>[] configClasses = getServletConfigClasses();
        if (!ObjectUtils.isEmpty(configClasses)) {
            context.register(configClasses);
        }
        return context;
    }
```

Comment: YOu don't as it will be set by the `DispatcherServlet` due to the fact that the `AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext` is `ServletContextAware`.

Answer (score 1):

Alright, let's break this down step by step:

### The Spring Framework Context Hierarchy

In Spring, there's a concept of a parent-child hierarchy of contexts. The root context is typically the context of the entire application, while the child contexts are more specialized contexts, often linked to specific servlets.

The `DispatcherServlet` in Spring MVC is typically associated with a child context, which is a specialization of the general application context. This child context is meant for web-specific components, like controllers, view resolvers, etc.

### The Role of ServletContext

The `ServletContext` is a standard Java EE interface that provides information about the web application and a way to interact with its container (like Tomcat). It's like a shared space where servlets in the same web application can communicate with each other.

### The Purpose of ctx.setServletContext(container)

When you do `ctx.setServletContext(container)`, you're linking the `ServletContext` of the web application to the Spring `ApplicationContext` you've just created.

#### Why is this necessary?

1. **Web Application Context**: By setting the `ServletContext`, you're
   effectively making the `ApplicationContext` a web application
   context. This allows it to understand its surrounding web
   environment and utilize web-specific features like resolving views,
   interpreting web-based scopes (e.g., `request`, `session`), etc.
2. **Resource Loading**: The `ServletContext` provides capabilities to load
   resources from the web application. For instance, if you have a view
   resolver that's resolving JSP files, it can utilize the
   `ServletContext` to find those JSP files within the web application.
3. **Scoped Beans**: Spring provides web-specific scopes (like `request`,
   `session`, etc.). In order to create and manage beans with such
   scopes, the `ApplicationContext` needs to be aware of the
   `ServletContext`.

### Is it Mandatory?

In many scenarios, if you don't set the `ServletContext`, your `ApplicationContext` might still work, but it won't be aware of the web environment. This means certain features, especially web-specific ones, might not function as expected.

### Comparison with createServletApplicationContext()

In the method `createServletApplicationContext()` you provided, the `ServletContext` isn't being explicitly set. It's possible that the setting of the `ServletContext` is done elsewhere, perhaps within the Spring framework itself when the created context is actually being used in association with a `DispatcherServlet`.

### Summary

The line `ctx.setServletContext(container)` is used to make the `ApplicationContext` aware of the web environment, allowing it to function correctly in a web application setting and utilize web-specific features provided by Spring.

References:

[Spring WebApplicationInitializer](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/WebApplicationInitializer.html)

[Java ServletContext](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html)

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH FOR SUCH A DETAILED ANSWER.